# Summing mysql json objects with multiple indexes

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

While selecting json data from the database I've ran into a problem.
Is there a way to extract data index by index.

I need this because I want to sum and group by name of the json item, I can achieve this if I extract first items from the array with:

```
DB::raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[0].name[0]")) as brand_name'), 
DB::raw('JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[0].brand_id[0]")) as brand_id'),
DB::raw('SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(resources, "$[0].quantity[0]")) as quantity')
```

And then I would group by $[0].name[0] and I would get unique results.

Data stored in sql:

```
[[{\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"brand_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 2}, 
{\"name\": \"Product 2\", \"brand_id\": \"3\", \"quantity\": 1}], 

[{\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"brand_id\": \"1\", \"quantity\": 2}, 
{\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"brand_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 5}], 

[{\"name\": \"Product 4\", \"brand_id\": \"4\", \"quantity\": 2}, 
{\"name\": \"Product 5\", \"brand_id\": \"5\", \"quantity\": 5}]]
```

I should sum the quantity of all products with the same name, and get unique response not multiple items with the same name, if you understand what I'm saying.
For example there should be only one

Product 1 with summed quantity of 7.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can grab the raw JSON string:

```
$rawjson = '[[{\"name\":\"Product 1\",\"brand_id\": \"2\",\"quantity\": 2},{\"name\":\"Product 2\",\"brand_id\": \"3\",\"quantity\": 1}],[{\"name\": \"Product 3\", \"brand_id\": \"1\",\"quantity\": 2},{\"name\": \"Product 1\", \"brand_id\": \"2\", \"quantity\": 5}],[{\"name\": \"Product 4\", \"brand_id\": \"4\",\"quantity\": 2},{\"name\": \"Product 5\", \"brand_id\": \"5\",\"quantity\": 5}]]';

$master = json_decode(stripslashes($rawjson), true);

$p1Sum = 0;
$p2Sum = 0;
$p3Sum = 0;
$p4Sum = 0;

foreach ($master as $subitems) {
    foreach ($subitems as $item) {
      $itemName = $item['name'];
      switch($itemName){
      case 'Product 1':
        $p1Sum += $item['quantity'];
        break;
       case 'Product 2':
        $p2Sum += $item['quantity'];
        break;
       case 'Product 3':
         $p3Sum += $item['quantity'];
         break;
       case 'Product 4':
         $p4Sum += $item['quantity'];
         break;
      }

    }
}

echo 'Product 1: ' . $p1Sum . "\r\n";
echo 'Product 2: ' . $p2Sum . "\r\n";
echo 'Product 3: ' . $p3Sum . "\r\n";
echo 'Product 4: ' . $p4Sum . "\r\n";
```

Will give you:

```
Product 1: 7
Product 2: 1
Product 3: 2
Product 4: 2
```

Comment: Yes I know how to do that with php, but my question is, is there a way to do this with a query?

Comment: You could possibly do a raw query using (JSON_CONTAINS)[https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains]

Comment: What should I run it agains? I don't quite understand the function, data is dynamical.

Comment: See examples for JSON_CONTAINS [here](https://www.qcode.in/use-mysql-json-field-in-laravel/):